# How to make a div in Electron scrollable

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, electron

I am writing a simple Markdown app in Electron. Currently, I just have a textarea, and a div, and some Javascript code that gets the text in the textarea, feeds it into Marked (a handy NPM module) and sets the content of the div with Jquery.

I have already done overflow: auto; in my css document, and tried all of the obvious solutions I have come across, and none of them work. My textarea scrolls fine, but the div does not. It simply cuts off the text at the bottom.

Here is my code : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jZprNL

html:

```
<div class="row fullHeight" id="container">
  <div class="column fullHeight " id="markdown">

    <textarea class="padding markdown-body nodrag" id="editor" placeholder="Write something briliant..."></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="column fullHeight" id="preview">
    <div class="padding markdown-body nodrag" id="output">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
 /* there are some styles here the interact with .row and .column for responcive grid arangement, they are long so I have not added them here */

#container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}
#editor {
    background-color: #f4f6f7;
    border-width: 0px;
    resize: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 5px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
#output {
    overflow: scroll;
    padding: 5px;
    padding-top: 15px;
}

/* a lot of these styles are irelevant to this question, and are simply here because of what I was doing with electron, but i might aswell add them */
```

JS:

```
$editor.on('input propertychange', function () {
  var outputHtml = marked($('#editor').val());
  $output.html(outputHtml);
  console.log($('#editor').val());
});

// note that this doesnt work because Node isnt installed and stuff, but this is a small part of the JS code anyway, incase it is usefull.
```

// edit added codepen

Comment: Share us you html code. Because we need you code to create a testing snippet.

Comment: `#` references an id. Within your css you use `.editor` that's a class. Does your div also have a class editor set?

Comment: slowjack2k, yes it does have the .editor class, but I really should use an id instead. Thank you for the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your example code. The following should show a scrollbar:

```
#output {
  overflow: scroll;
  padding: 5px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  width: 90%;
  height: 100px;
}
```

You can use a height of 100% when one surrounding element has a fixed height. The code you did provide show's only relative heights. If you choose a width of 100% it can happen that you don't see a scrollbar. But still the div element is scrollable.

Furthermore you'r using markdown it's likely that you also include a markdown related stylesheet, which interferes with your stylesheet.

Comment: Ahh yes, I was using the Github Markdown stylesheet, which was interfering with mine. Thank you for the answer

Answer (score 1):

you need to have a wrapping div.

i.ex

```
<div class="window">
   <div class="scrollable">
     <p>some long text heigher than 500px......</p>
   </div>
</div>

.window {
   height: 500px;
   width: 500px;
   overflow: hidden;
}

.scrollable {
  overflow: scroll;
  height: 100%;
}
```

codepen link 
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yvqLOK

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. From what I can tell it appears to be an issue with either how Electron (or rather Chromium) handles scrolling, (which seems unlikely), or with how I am editing the content of the div with Javascript. Anyway, thank you for your answer.